# Apache httpd alias/directory conditionally configured based on environment variable

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

We have an Apache httpd server configured to allow browsing of a specific file directory. We'd like to set that directory location based on an environment variable that specifies where the system is deployed (dev, qa, prod). Here is my attempt to do that:

```
<If "osenv('APP_ENV') == 'dev'">
  LogMessage "The value of APP_ENV is dev"
  Define DATA_MOUNT /data/AA_images
</If>
<Else>
  LogMessage "The value of APP_ENV is other"
  Define DATA_MOUNT /data/DIM_Factory
</Else>


Alias /data ${DATA_MOUNT}
<Directory ${DATA_MOUNT}>
  Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
  IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort FoldersFirst NameWidth=32
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I can see from the logs that "The value of APP_ENV is dev" is correctly triggered, but the *second* Define is being set, not the first. When I start the server, I'm getting the DIM_Factory directory. Why is that? Seems like the Define commands are not being evaluated as part of the If/Else block.

Is there a different way I should be doing this?